# Trouble declaring a public string inside an event - C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have an event where I want to declare a `public string` which denotes the `filePath` from my `openFileDialog`. I want to do this so I can access the `filePath` in another form.

Here is how I have tried to do so:

```
private void confirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog ofd = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //DO STUFF WITH SELECTED FILE
        }
        public string fileName = ofd.FileName;
    }
```

I get a bunch of syntax errors when trying to declare the string as public, and I have also tried changing the event to a public event,however this does not solve the problem.

Any help would be appreciated,thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't declare properties or fields inside methods (or events).

You want something more like this, I suspect.

```
public string filename { get; set; }

private void confirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog ofd = new SaveFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //DO STUFF WITH SELECTED FILE
    }
    filename = ofd.FileName;
}
```

The reason is that anything you declare inside the method body is scoped only *within* that method body. Thus, something being marked `public` doesn't make much sense. By pulling it out of the method body and simply referencing it from there, you're able to do a bit more.

Comment: To go a little deeper: All standard variables declared in the method body are only accessible during the method execution (with a few exceptions), so your public variable would be disposed after the method execution and wouldnt exist anymore. BTW: Go give him the best answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring that string not as public. Its inside the method. Try:

```
public string fileName;
private void confirmButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog ofd = new SaveFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //DO STUFF WITH SELECTED FILE
        fileName = ofd.FileName;
    }

}
```